# Relation between a null space and a line.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a matrix $T$ and a line $x=y=z$. Lets say I find the null space of $T$ to be $\{\begin{bmatrix}-1\\ 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}-1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}\}$. Is it correct to say that the nullspace of $T$ is the plane of $x=y=z$?

Comment: No, because the word "of" is unclear here. What is the plane of a line? If you say "perpendicular to" instead of "of", then it becomes correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume that you mean the null space of $T$ is the space spanned by those two vectors. What you'll find is that the null space of $T$ is the plane determined by the lines $y=-x,z=0$ and $z=-x,y=0$.

It is worth noting that this plane is perpendicular to the line $x=y=z$ (and this is fairly readily proven, as it is perpendicular to the two lines mentioned above), so if that's what you meant by "the plane of the line", then you're correct, but you should be precise.